# Invoke method for multi thread application?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, invoke, begininvoke, measurement-studio

I have a bug in my application which is the same as [here](http://forums.ni.com/t5/Measurement-Studio-for-NET/Waveform-Graph-quot-X-quot-Error/m-p/217817/highlight/true#M1668) which this person was running into the same problem.  My application is multi threaded where the worker thread is updating the Waveformgraph on the UI.  I believe that is where my problem is and why, periodically, and on occassion I get a big red X in at least one of my waveformgraph objects when running the application.  From reading and research, I need to use an Invoke or BeginInvoke method?  Can someone please explain better and provide a sample code that is relevant to my code? The samples that I've found so far still have me hazy on how I need to do this or what I need to do.  Thank you for your help.

This code is on the swScopeOnOff click event, main thread.

```
  thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf dataAcquiring)
  thread2.Start()
```

This code is in dataAcquiring Sub

```
  Public Sub dataAcquiring()
    'While Scope switch is on, stream each Ai channel's data continuously to its respective WaveForm graph
    Do While swScopeOnOff.Value = True
            data = reader.ReadWaveform(readRate)
            i = 0
            For Each WaveformGraph In WFGS
                WaveformGraph.PlotWaveformAppend(data(i)) 'This line is updating the UI's waveform graphs
                i += 1
            Next
            i = 0
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper, thread-safe invocation is actually not as hard as one might think (not even for thread-safe events, but that's irrelevant for this question).

I would recommend you to use the normal `Invoke` method, such as `Me.Invoke()` (where `Me` is the current form, if not, use `Form1` or whatever it's called instead). Using `BeginInvoke()` may be asynchronous but it stacks memory usage and can cause memory leaks if `EndInvoke()` is not called correctly.

If you target .NET 4.0 or higher you can simply do like this:

```
Me.Invoke(Sub() WaveformGraph.PlotWaveformAppend(data(i)))
```

However if you target .NET 3.5 or lower it requires a few more lines of code.

```
'Outside your Sub.
Delegate Sub WaveformAppendDelegate(ByRef WaveformGraph, ByRef data)

'Create a new sub.
Public Sub AppendData(ByRef WaveformGraph, ByRef data)
    WaveformGraph.PlotWaveformAppend(data)
End Sub

'Inside your sub, when you're going to invoke.
Me.Invoke(New WaveformAppendDelegate(AddressOf AppendData), WaveformGraph, data(i))
```

Comment: I am targeting .NET 4.0, so that made it simple.  Thank you very much for the code and "how to" and the explanation of each.

Comment: @busarider29 : You're welcome. .NET 4.0 is one of the best updates in my opinion. <3